# Pegar imagem Preview de um vídeo / listFiles() não funciona

Tags: java, aplicação-desktop

Estou com dois problema em um projeto super simples que estou desenvolvendo nos quais eu não encontrei uma solução no Fórum e nem no Google, o projeto é um Gerenciamento de vídeo.

Vou deixar abaixo o link do Github para aqueles que tiverem curiosidade, queiram aprimorar/refatorar o projeto ou queria um exemplo simples para estudar.

Github: https://github.com/wilsontamarozzi/movie-list-java

**Problemas**

1. Como pegar a imagem Preview (miniatura) de um vídeo de qualquer formato?! Já procurei no Google mas só vi tutoriais de como gerar um thumbnail do vídeo utilizando `xuggler`, mas isso vai fazer com que eu tenha que armazenar isso em algum lugar e não é algo que eu queria fazer por eu ter que controlar isso mais tarde.
2. Tenho uma pasta no qual o `listFiles()` não funciona, as permissões de leitura e escrita estão tudo Ok e nada. Simplesmente me retorna `null`, alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Ninguem tem alguma ideia?

Comment: A pergunta #1 parece uma duplicata desta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/95988/pegar-imagem-preview-de-um-v%C3%ADdeo-listfiles-n%C3%A3o-funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Decodificar vídeos

Em relação ao problema **#1**, não existe uma solução mágica para ler imagens de *qualquer* formato de vídeo.

Cada formato de vídeo precisa de um algoritmo específico para interpretá-lo e dificilmente uma única implementação vai cobrir todos os formatos.

Mesmo que algumas bibliotecas (ou grupo de bibliotecas) consigam ler vários formatos comuns, sempre há alguns formatos proprietários ou variações que acabam causando problemas.

## Abordagens

Duas soluções básicas para miniaturas seriam:

### Pré-armazenar as miniaturas

Armazene as miniaturas juntamente com os arquivos de vídeo.

Se você tem algum controle sobre como os arquivos de vídeo são gerados ou incluídos no diretório, esta seria a melhor solução.

Use qualquer ferramenta via linha de comando para gerar a miniatura e deixe seu programa Java simples e rápido.

### Gerar a miniatura sob demanda

Este é a abordagem possível quando você não tem controle sobre os vídeos.

Decodificar o vídeo a partir do seu programa pode ser conveniente por um lado, mas tenha em mente que vai aumentar muito a complexidade do programa e potencialmente vai afetar o desempenho de um modo bem negativo. Pense em renderizar 500 vídeos de uma pasta qualquer.

Talvez seja necessário criar uma fila para processar os vídeos e trabalhar com diferentes *threads* para não travar o programa e permitir o cancelamento no caso do usuário não querer esperar a operação terminar.

#### Xuggler

Não entendi qual o problema em manter as bibliotecas usadas pelo [xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler). Muitos programas e ferramentas acompanham bibliotecas diferentes.

O argumento de "ter que controlar isso mais tarde" não faz sentido porque qualquer dependência adicionada no seu projeto terá que ser gerenciada.

Qual exatamente a dificuldade em *controlar* isso se você colocar as bibliotecas junto com seu programa ao distribuir?

Pelo que li na [documentação](http://www.xuggle.com/public/documentation/java/api/), o xuggler é um wrapper para as bibliotecas nativas FFMPEG, usadas em diversos projetos. A vantagem de usar essas bibliotecas é que elas já possuem maturidade e são confiáveis.

#### JCodec

Outra alternativa seria o [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/), uma implementação feita puramente em Java.

A primeira página já traz um exemplo de como extrair um frame do vídeo para uma imagem:

```
int frameNumber = 150;
BufferedImage frame = FrameGrab.getFrame(new File("arquivo.mp4"), frameNumber);
ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("frame_150.png"));
```

Entretanto, como é de se esperar de uma biblioteca menos utilizada, ela suporta poucos formatos: AVC, H.264 em MP4, ISO BMF e Quicktime. Suponho que ela também tenha menos aderência a variações desses formatos.

Embora tenha atualizações recentes nesta biblioteca, provavelmente as atualizações para novos formatos ou mesmo já existentes serão poucas ou mais demoradas, já que não parece haver um grande envolvimento no projeto.

## Problema com `listFiles()`

O problema com o `listFiles` pode ser causado se o processo Java não tem permissões para ler da pasta.

Pode ser também que o diretório que você passou seja inválido. Por exemplo, eu fiz um teste passando `~` (diretório do usuário) e não funcionou. Entretanto, passando o caminho absoluto deu certo.

Também usaria a API mais nova do Java. Exemplo:

```
//extensões aceitas
PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:*.{txt,log}");
//diretório de busca
Path diretorio = Paths.get("/my/dir");
//permite links simbólicos
EnumSet<FileVisitOption> options = EnumSet.of(FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);
//navega no diretório
Files.walkFileTree(diretorio, options, 1,
        new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                //verifica se não é um diretório e se tem uma das extensões esperadas
                if (!attrs.isDirectory() && matcher.matches(file.getFileName())) {
                    System.out.println(file.toString());
                }
                return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
            }
        });
```

Veja a documentação relevante sobre o [`walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html#filevisitor) e sobre o [`PathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html).

## Considerações

Define a melhor abordagem para o seu caso e lembre-se que qualquer uma delas terá seus pontos positivos e negativos.

Comment: Muito boa recomendação sobre o `walkFileTree`, nele é possível verificar os arquivos que houveram falhas, não conhecia e funcionou perfeitamente. O problema que eu estava tendo com o `ListFiles` era algo sobre os atributos na pasta precisei usar um comando para resetar os atributos. Sobre o `Xuggler` tive que realmente gerar as thumbnail mas estou tendo aquela mensagem de erro listada na resposta do amigo acima. Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Answer (score 3):

Sobre o `Xuggler` e levando em consideração as colocações do @utluiz, funciona perfeitamente, adaptado às minhas necessidades ficou perfeito (que é bem semelhante ao que você esta fazendo) [e também funcionou perfeitamente no stackoverflow.com para um usuário em questão](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/mediatool/demos/DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java):

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.File;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaListenerAdapter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.event.IVideoPictureEvent;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;

/**
 *  * @author aclarke
 *    @author trebor
 */

public class DecodeAndCaptureFrames extends MediaListenerAdapter
{
  private int mVideoStreamIndex = -1;
  private boolean gotFirst = false;
  private String saveFile;
  private Exception e;
  /** Construct a DecodeAndCaptureFrames which reads and captures
   * frames from a video file.
   * 
   * @param filename the name of the media file to read
   */

  public DecodeAndCaptureFrames(String videoFile, String saveFile)throws Exception
  {
    // create a media reader for processing video
    this.saveFile = saveFile;
    this.e = null;
     IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(videoFile);

    // stipulate that we want BufferedImages created in BGR 24bit color space
    reader.setBufferedImageTypeToGenerate(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);


    // note that DecodeAndCaptureFrames is derived from
    // MediaReader.ListenerAdapter and thus may be added as a listener
    // to the MediaReader. DecodeAndCaptureFrames implements
    // onVideoPicture().

    reader.addListener(this);

    // read out the contents of the media file, note that nothing else
    // happens here.  action happens in the onVideoPicture() method
    // which is called when complete video pictures are extracted from
    // the media source

      while (reader.readPacket() == null && !gotFirst);

      if (e != null)
          throw e;
  }



  /** 
   * Called after a video frame has been decoded from a media stream.
   * Optionally a BufferedImage version of the frame may be passed
   * if the calling {@link IMediaReader} instance was configured to
   * create BufferedImages.
   * 
   * This method blocks, so return quickly.
   */

  public void onVideoPicture(IVideoPictureEvent event)
  {
    try
    {
      // if the stream index does not match the selected stream index,
      // then have a closer look

      if (event.getStreamIndex() != mVideoStreamIndex)
      {
        // if the selected video stream id is not yet set, go ahead an
        // select this lucky video stream

        if (-1 == mVideoStreamIndex)
          mVideoStreamIndex = event.getStreamIndex();

        // otherwise return, no need to show frames from this video stream

        else
          return;
      }

      ImageIO.write(event.getImage(), "jpg", new File(saveFile));
      gotFirst = true;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.e = e;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, eu cheguei a ver uma classe que realiza o mesmo processo, mas tanto a minha quanto a sua está me apresentando essa mensagem, você saberia dizer o que pode ser isso? `10:11:04.459 [Finalizer] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing dangling Container (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/Container.cpp:146)
10:11:04.464 [Finalizer] DEBUG com.xuggle.xuggler - Closing dangling StreamCoder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:96)`

Comment: Você esta usando Tomcat ?

Comment: Se estiver adicione as variáveis para o processo de inicialização do Tomcat (arquivo setenv.sh), daqui onde estou não deu para acessar a wiki.xuggle.com, tem um tutorial que ensina o passo a passo, acho que você terá que reinstalar o Xuggler. Procura ai sobre 'Xuggler e Tomcat' você encontrara o que estou falando (variáveis de ambiente) e se conseguir abrir a Wiki dará certinho (a wiki aqui esta dando tempo limite)

Answer (score 1):

1. No caso do Windows (sistema mais utilizado), ele cria thumbnails em um arquivo Thumbs.db. Se você conseguir acessá-lo poderá pegar essas thumbnails.
   O ruim dessa abordagem é depender de recursos do sistema operacional (o ue não é recomendado).
2. Se você já consegue gerar a thumbnails sem problemas você pode criar uma pasta oculta (ou não) junto com os vídeos em questão. Com um caminho padrão e nomenclaturas padrão você sabe que as miniaturas sempre estarão lá (pode verificar se estão ou não e criar).